# Hadoop Processing time in clustered and standalone system

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hbase, distributed-computing

I have set up a 3 node hadoop cluster (1 Namenode, 2 data nodes) and hbase on top of the same hdfs. Each node are 512 MB Ubuntu Virtual box images running on my windows 8 Machine(Intel i5,4GB RAM, 2.4Ghz)
I have configured hbase-hadoop based on this blog
http://ankitasblogger.blogspot.in/2011/01/hadoop-cluster-setup.html

I have written a program, which analyzes US Census Data which is approximately has 500,000 records(reduced set). I am just reading the file(from hdfs) in MAP task and storing it is HBASE . and later retrieving data based on a filter.

When I run the program in a stand alone(512 MB Virtual Machine) hadoop-hbase, it takes around 23 minutes. But when  I run the same jar in the cluster(512*3 MB) it takes upwards of 40 minutes.

Why is the cluster taking more time to process? or is it a expected result ?

Answer (score 1):

running a cluster in virtual-machines will only slow down your map-reduce (because of the overhead from running the virtual-os and multiple hadoop instances) especially if you run out of memory and it has to use the swap from the host os.

keep in mind that the virtual-machines all share 1 physical CPU and should only be used for development.

Comment: I have 3 Virtual box runing, all of them share 1 CPU? or will each VBox  utilize a physical CPU ?

Comment: No matter how many CPUs your machine has, it is bad practice to use virtual machines for benchmarking. Moreover, it is perfectly normal that your program is slower in distributed mode, notably due to the overhead caused by network communication.

Comment: @Xion345. while true the question wasn't about best practices. I'm just trying to answer the question directly.